# Adding templating to D3

Tags: d3.js, templating

http://bl.ocks.org/JohnBerryman/2295155

This is my attempt to add templating to D3. I drew the original face in Inkscape and then I turned the SVG into an iCanHaz template and made the template variables correspond to facial measurements. This way I could define a face (and by extension, whatever else) and I could easily instantiate the face, or even let the face change by just updating the data bound to the face object. The first part of the code (if you scroll past the demo) is a patch to D3, and then the rest of the code uses that patch.

Unfortunately I didn't ever get to put nice tests around this and submit a pull request to Mr. Bostock.

Questions:

1. I'm still new to D3. Is this something that can otherwise be done in D3 and I just don't know about it.
2. Is this generally useful? Is it worth submitting a pull request?
3. Is it d3-esque? Does the code here represent code appropriate for d3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@meetamit is on the right way but you've to use a polyfill to apply `d3.select.html` method on SVG. This method uses `innerHTML` and isn't supported on SVG elements. Check the
[d3.select.html reference](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-html)

[My solution on bl.ocks](http://bl.ocks.org/jkutianski/7328902)

[D3 Templating Plugin](https://github.com/jkutianski/d3-templating)

Comment: I found that the `true` as second parameter on `ich.head(d, true)` isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with ICanHaz specifically (although worked plenty with templating in general), so I may be missing something crucial. But, it seems to me that extending D3 is unnecessary for this.

Considering that a compiled template (ich or otherwise) is simply a function that returns html, you could just do this:

```
vis.selectAll('.head').data(data)
  .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'head')
    .html(ich.head) // <--- THIS
    .attr('transform',function(d) {return 'translate('+ d.x +' '+ d.y +')'});
```

This will call `ich.head` for every element, passing in `d` and `i`. So unless the passing of `i` into an ich template causes undesired behavior, I'm pretty sure you'd achieve the same results.

If passing `i` the into ich template is a problem, the workaround would be

```
.html(function(d,i) { return ich.head(d); })
```

Comment: That seemed like a good idea, but I get errors when I try it. `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'html'`

Comment: @JohnBerryman My bad... forgot that you need to append an element before calling `.html()` on it. I modified my code to show this. I guess therein lies the difference: your modification of D3 removes the need to add the node (and the "head" class). Despite that, I still don't think it justifies modifying D3, but you could take that up with Mr Bostock :)

Answer (score 0):

@meetamit's answer is **mostly** correct. However, to make this work properly I had to use the raw HTML output of the iCanHaz template, which requires a slightly different call to ICH:

```
vis.selectAll('.head').data(data)
.enter()
.append('g')
.attr('class', 'head')
.html(function(d){ return ich.head(d, true); } ) // <--- THIS
.attr('transform',function(d) {return 'translate('+ d.x +' '+ d.y +')'});
```

Notice the "true" parameter, which tells ICH to return the HTML instead of the object.